# S3 Dynamic Storage on Swisscom

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, emc, object-storage, swisscomdev

I'm trying to use S3 Dynamic Storage as a drop in replacement for AWS S3. I'm using it through Ruby with [carrierwave-aws](https://github.com/sorentwo/carrierwave-aws).

The only change I made was to use different credentials (I got key & secret from Swisscom Developer Console) and https://ds31s3.swisscom.com as the endoint.

Now can't get over `Access Denied` error message from carrierwave, although I can see from logs what looks like a proper request:

```
[httplog] Connecting: documents.ds31s3.swisscom.com:443
[httplog] Sending: PUT http://documents.ds31s3.swisscom.com:443/uploads/financial_information/document/3/17/erd.pdf
[httplog] Header: content-type: application/pdf
[httplog] Header: accept-encoding:
[httplog] Header: user-agent: aws-sdk-ruby2/2.1.29 ruby/2.2.3 x86_64-darwin15 resources
[httplog] Header: x-amz-acl: public-read
[httplog] Header: expect: 100-continue
[httplog] Header: content-md5: 3j2Km8Dc2/50bZyh4a1Qyw==
[httplog] Header: date: Wed, 11 May 2016 14:21:56 GMT
[httplog] Header: authorization: AWS _REDACTED_MY_SECRETS_
[httplog] Header: content-length: 62556
[httplog] Header: accept: */*
[httplog] Status: 403
[httplog] Benchmark: 1.3060949619975872 seconds
[httplog] Header: date: Wed, 11 May 2016 14:21:57 GMT
[httplog] Header: server: Apache
[httplog] Header: content-length: 110
[httplog] Header: content-type: application/xml
[httplog] Response: (not available yet)
```

Anyone know what that's about?

Comment: According to the logs you are using http and not http**s**. Try to use http**s**.

Comment: please try with a GUI S3 browser if everything works with your credentials. Please update the questions with results.

Comment: I used my credentials with https://github.com/swisscom/dynstrg-howto (the official Swisscom example for Dynamic Storage) and got the same problem.  I then used this app with AWS and later credentials for Exoscale's S3 compatible service, and they both worked out of the box. 
That's why I'm going with Exoscale for now. Swisscom's documentation/support was very poor/slow - I wouldn't want to stick with them for serious stuff.